# Running Shell Script on Jenkins Windows Slave

Tags: windows, shell, jenkins, scripting, cygwin

I have installed Jenkins on Windows10. I am trying to run a shell script which create the folder

```
#!bin/bash 

DIR1=ShellScript/folder1
if [ -d "$DIR1" ]; then
    echo removing folder 1
    rm -rf "$DIR1"
fi

mkdir "$DIR1"
```

I have installed cygwin on windows and set the executable on Jenkins cygwin64/bin/sh
[image]

When I am running the build fails by giving error Permission Denied.Here are the logs

```
    Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CreateDir
FSSCM.checkout C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ShellScript to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CreateDir
FSSCM.check completed in 10 milliseconds
Set build name.
New build name is '#Create Dir2'
$ C:\cygwin64\bin\cygpath -w C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe
[CreateDir] $ C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins1863454407248508967.sh
+ ./MyShell.sh
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins1863454407248508967.sh: line 2: ./MyShell.sh: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Set build name.
New build name is '#Create Dir2'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please If anyone can suggest how to solve this?
 Thank You

Comment: what permission has the script and the `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` ?

Comment: Probably your script doesn't have an executable permission to run (chmod +x MyShell.sh).
Anyway, when in Rome, speak Italian,,, When on Windows write Batch script...
You better write a 'bat' script that do the same thing instead of a shell script (use 'RMDIR' and 'MKDIR' commands)

Comment: When I am running it directly from cygwin mintty terminal it works fine might this is a issue with jenkins permission how can I edit those??